# how to transfer a row length to an col lenght and reversed if they have not the equal length (java)

Tags: java, arrays

hi my code works if the array has the same length for rows and cols.
but when they are different they don't work. how can i transfer the length to my new array?pls help

```
public class rotatearray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3,4},
                {4, 5,6,5},
                {7, 8, 9,7}};
        rotate(a);
    }

    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a) {
        int[][] b = new int[a.length][a.length];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
                b[j][i] = a[a.length-i-1][a.length-j-1];
                System.out.print(b[j][j]);
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to transfer data to a new array?

Comment: Of course. An array is an OBJECT, just like String. The only difference this object is a "pointer" to a "collection" of other object references.  You can use the `Arrays` class to make copies of arrays.  MAKE SURE YOU READ THE API CAREFULLY IF YOU DO.  Alternatively, you can use a loop to grab a value from one location, and put it in the newly created array.

Comment: I'd argue that the array is a reference to a collection of other references...not a pointer.  Java doesn't expose pointers to the developer.

Comment: Question:  are you rotating these around (as in, clockwise/anticlockwise), or are you transposing them instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem came from assigning the row and column length of the new array, based only off the length of the original array. The solution need to take both of these values and swap them

I declare variables for the original row and col length. This makes it easier to see at a glance what they are supposed to mean.

You'll also need to assign array 'a' with the return value of the rotate method, since the size of the original array cannot be altered after creation.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayRotator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 4, 5, 6, 5 }, { 7, 8, 9, 7 } };

        // uses rotate method to assign new value to array
        a = rotate(a);

    }

    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] arr) {
        // return if supplied array is empty
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return new int[0][0];
        }

        // create new array with swapped length for rows and columns
        int origRows = arr.length;
        int origCols = arr[0].length;
        int[][] rotatedArr = new int[origCols][origRows];

        for (int i = 0; i < origRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < origCols; j++) {
                // Rotate array 90 degrees clockwise:
                // new row <- original column
                // new column <- original row, reversed
                rotatedArr[j][i] = arr[origRows - 1 - i][j];
            }
        }

        return rotatedArr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER: You **CANNOT** resize an array once it is created.

To "rotate" your array, you would have to create another 2D array in which the length of the column equals the length of the rows of the original and the length of the rows equals the length of the column of the original.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the length of the matrix rows to get the size of rows and columns. That's why it only works on square matrices. Try this and you will tell the difference:

```
int[][] m = new int[3][4];
System.out.println(m.length);
System.out.println(m[0].length);
```

Comment: but do not harcode `m[0].length`, it's not necessarily the same as `m[1].length` and so on. The part that does `j<a[i].length` is the correct way of reading each sub arrays lenght.

Comment: Of course, my point was just to clarify that the numbers given in each print would be different.